# jQuery: How to check if a date input field in empty

Tags: jquery

What I have right now.

```
$('form input[name="birthDate"])').blur(function () {
      var dob = $("#dob").val();
      if(dob == "") {
        $("#dobAlert").show();
        $("#laba").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $("#dobAlert").hide();
      }
    });
```

The #laba is a button that I want to disable if the input is empty.
I know I can disable the button if I put `required` in the input tag. But the problem I have is that it doesn't show the alert.

[Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/karateka11/p1y8tazr/)

Comment: You should put your code into a JSFiddle

Comment: try verify if $("#dob").val() is a Falsy like this `if(!$("#dob").val())`

Comment: Tip: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to toggle disabled.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is about email validation, not date.

Comment: I put the code into JsFiddle. I also tried if(!$("#dob").val()) and it's still not working.

Comment: .prop() - the answer is already in the comments

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that it doesn't show the alert message. I updated the Jsfiddle link :)

Comment: Your selector is invalid because has an extra bracket in the end: `form input[name="birthDate"])`.

Comment: Input of type date will have always something, so you can check if it contains a valid date: `!Date.parse(dob)`. http://jsfiddle.net/6hr5j99p/

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: ah - yes @MelanciaUK - make that an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inputs of type date won't return empty, because there will be the date placeholder there (dd/mm/yyyy).
You can test if the value is a valid date.

First, fix your jQuery selector, because there's an extra bracket there. Also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to toggle the disabled property.

```
$('input[name="birthDate"]').blur(function () {
    var dob = $("#dob").val();

    if (!Date.parse(dob)) {
        $("#dobAlert").show();
        $("#laba").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#dobAlert").hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hr5j99p/)

Another way is to check for the Falsy like @Callebe suggested:

```
$('input[name="birthDate"]').blur(function () {
    if (!$("#dob").val()) {
        $("#dobAlert").show();
        $("#laba").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#dobAlert").hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hr5j99p/1/)